# How to free a node linked into another list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I am working on my University Assignment in C programming that emulates a musical record renting shop. Though, I am having some troubles freeing the memory that contains the username of the persons who have rented a certain record, in the *return_record* function.

Here are the data structures:

Username:

```
typedef struct{
    char username[u];
    struct customer_u * next;
}customer_u;
```

Record:

```
typedef struct{
    char title[u];
    char artist[u];
    int year;
    float price;
    int quant;
    int rent;
    customer_u * head;
    struct record * next;
}record;
```

About the *free* function, that's what I've done:

Here's the code:

```
void return_record(record * head, char * username){
        char title[u];
        puts("record to give back:");
        scanf("%s", title);
                while((head!=NULL) && ((strcmp(title, head->title)) == 0)){
//                              printf("%s\n", head->title); verify
                                customer head2 = head->head;
                                while((head2!=NULL)&&((strcmp(head2->username, username)) == 0){
                                                free(head2);
                                        head2 = head2->next;
                                }
                        head = head->next;
                }
}
```

It happens that I've got an empty line after that (which is the freed one), and I am not able no more to put any other customer in that record node.

What am I doing wrong? I guess that I should make that empty line be replaced with the predecessor or next node, somehow.

Thanks in advance!
A

Comment: `head = head->next;` is update to the local variable and no influence on the caller function. Use double pointer in argument for `record ** head`  or return the updated `record` for changes to reflect

Comment: Your example will _not_ compile because you're doing: `customer head2` and but you _use_ it as a pointer, so you want `customer *head2` [a typo when posting I imagine]. But, more importantly, you are doing `free(head2); head2 = head2->next;`. You are dereferencing a pointer _after_ it's been freed, which is UB [undefined behavior]. To fix this, do: `customer *next = head2->next; free(head2); head2 = next;`